# change custom page to editable CMS, page shows blank

Tags: admin, cms

After deleting both the template and layout pages of a custom page in our store I recreated the page in the admin CMS panel.  When I entered the URL I am brought to a page that is now blank.  What is causing this?  How do I push my CMS pages to functionaly?

thx.

Comment: If you turn on template hints is the page still completely blank?

Comment: @JamesAnelay Yes -- well, the header + footer are filled in nicely (as they are on every page) however, the content block, while existent, does not have anything within it.  Also, I just turned 'template hints' on and yes, there is text all over the place, lol.

Comment: It sounds like the route for your old custom page still exists so your not seeing the CMS page your seeing the old page but with not content as you deleted the template and layout. Meaning your left with the default layout with no content.

If you right click then View Source and find this tag <body class=".... what is in the class= part?

Comment: @JamesAnelay <body class=" ($urlKey)-index-index">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a custom module that created a new frontend route. Simply removing the template and layout related to it is not enough to then be able to use the same URL as a CMS page (If you change the cms url to $url-new I bet that would work). Because now the page is loading that custom route with the  styling.

You will probably have a custom module that in it's /etc/config.xml does something like

```
<routers>
            <contacts>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>custom-url</frontName>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
```

If that is all this extension does you can remove it, if it does more you'll need to remove that routers node. What that modules is you will have to figure out yourself. Hopefully it is named well.